# direct file upload to Google bucket with REST API

Tags: rest, go, google-cloud-platform

Following the Go [example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-go), I have this code to upload a file to a Google bucket:

```
func uploadFile(bucket string, uploadFilePath string, destFilePath string) error {
    os.Setenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "./credential.json")
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("storage.NewClient: %v", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    // Open local file.
    f, err := os.Open(uploadFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("os.Open: %v", err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Second*50)
    defer cancel()
    o := client.Bucket(bucket).Object(destFilePath)
    o = o.If(storage.Conditions{DoesNotExist: true})
    
    // Upload an object with storage.Writer.
    wc := o.NewWriter(ctx)
    if _, err = io.Copy(wc, f); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("io.Copy: %v", err)
    }
    if err := wc.Close(); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Writer.Close: %v", err)
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    bucket := "g1-mybucket-001"
    targetFilePath := "./somefile.txt"
    destFilePath := "it_poc_test_folder/somefile.txt"
    err := uploadFile(bucket, targetFilePath, destFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Errorf("Error uplolading file: %v", err))
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%s uploaded to %s.\n", targetFilePath, destFilePath)
    }
}
```

Now I plan to wrap it to create a REST API for file upload.  I then realize that the code is for upload a local file only.  How can I wrap it so that the file would go straight to the bucket, without first uploading it to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of file upload [examples out there](https://tutorialedge.net/golang/go-file-upload-tutorial/), the gist being:

```
func uploadFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    // ... 
    r.ParseMultipartForm(10 << 20)
    f, handler, err := r.FormFile("myFile")
    if err != nil {
        // handle err
    }
    defer f.Close()
    // ...
}
```

So just simply pass the `f` body of the file upload on to your cloud upload logic as if it were a local file:

```
// same code - different `f` source

// Upload an object with storage.Writer.
wc := o.NewWriter(ctx)
if _, err = io.Copy(wc, f); err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("io.Copy: %v", err)
}
```